# Cocoa Pods Incompatible Character Encoding, When Installing RestKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, cocoapods

Hi im new to cocoaPods and this is the first time ive attempted to set it up, im trying to add RestKit to my project but when i run `pod install` i get the error seen below.

```
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:13:in `report': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:59:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:374:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Im still new to this so im unsure where i have gone wrong i checked online and found similar questions but none that solved by problem. All of my commands in the terminal are below to show what i have done so far i think i set cocoa pods correctly and the issue is with the pod file but im unsure. Also the contents of the pod file are below. Thank you for any help.

Terminal:

```
CocoaPods 0.37.0.rc.1 is available.
To update use: `gem install cocoapods --pre`
[!] This is a test version we'd love you to try.

For more information see http://blog.cocoapods.org
and the CHANGELOG for this version http://git.io/BaH8pQ.

Setup completed
Some-MacBook-Pro:Articles Some$ touch podfile
Some-MacBook-Pro:Articles Some$ open -a TextEdit PodFile
Some-MacBook-Pro:Articles Some$ pod install
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/user_interface/error_report.rb:13:in `report': incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT (Encoding::CompatibilityError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:59:in `report_error'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:374:in `handle_exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:315:in `rescue in run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/claide-0.8.1/lib/claide/command.rb:303:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:46:in `run'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/cocoapods-0.36.4/bin/pod:44:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
Some-MacBook-Pro:Articles Some$ open a- TextEdit PodFile
The files /Users/Some/Desktop/RW-Tutorials/Articles/a- and /Users/Some/Desktop/RW-Tutorials/Articles/TextEdit do not exist.
Some-MacBook-Pro:Articles Some$
```

PodFile:

```
platform :iOS, ‘8.0’
pod ‘RestKit’, ’~> 0.20.0’
```

Comment: pod init you have to give, then only it will create a pod

Comment: try with `platform :iOS, '8.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'` (note the quote characters used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat your `’` to `'`.

Either copy/paste the "to" example below or backspace your `’` and manually type `'`

```
platform :iOS, ‘8.0’
pod ‘RestKit’, ’~> 0.20.0’
```

to

```
platform :iOS, '8.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
```

then run your pod install/update

Comment: This one has bitten me more more than once :-D

Comment: Yes, my problem was this case.

Answer (score 0):

Terminal and type the following command:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Next, you need to install CocoaPods. Type this command in Terminal:

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Enter this command in Terminal to complete the setup of CocoaPods:

```
pod setup
```

Open Terminal and navigate to the directory containing your  project by using the cd command:

```
cd ~/Path/To/Folder/Containing/yourprojectName
```

Next enter this command:

```
pod init
```

Type this command to open Podfile  for editing:

```
open -a Xcode Podfile
```

Add these files to your pod file

```
platform :iOS, '8.0'
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.20.0'
```

Then you need to enter the following to finish

```
pod install
```

After this open the workspace on your project folder